# Strange behaviour on java method : isAssignableFrom(Class<?>)

Tags: java

If you try the following piece of code ( I've tried it on Java 6) :

```
System.out.println(Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(Set.class));
```

it prints out : `false` but I was expecting to print out : `true` because javadoc is saying :

`Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter.`

BUT Collection is a superclass of Set : `public interface Set<E> extends Collection<E>` .

So what is the explanation of this strange behaviour?

Comment: You're importing the wrong `Collection` type. It should be `java.util.Collection`. Or maybe java 6 is messed up. It works on 7. Or what @Marco13 below said.

Comment: Or the wrong `Set` type. It should be `java.util.Set` :-)

Comment: You were right , imports made my day today :) ...

Comment: It returns true for me, so check if you import correct classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are either importing the wrong `Collection.class` or the wrong `Set.class`.

Please note that there are some common pitfalls when using the `isAssignableFrom` method on `Collection` classes: I often note that people mix up the parameters so they call `Set.class.isAssignableFrom(Collection.class)` instead of calling `Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(Set.class)`.

Another problem which often roars up its ugly head is related to the `Map.class` which **is not** a `Collection`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate that you took the time to add the common pitfalls part , which I must admit that it was a pitfall for me at first( when I first started using reflection).